# Javascript Validation Dropdown and Text Input

Tags: javascript, validation, textinput

I've searched all over and cannot find a nice solution or if it's possible with client-side verification.

My client is asking that a user be restricted to a fixed-length digit combination based on a selection in a drop down.

**Example:**
*Drop Down Selection*
Utility A
Utility B
Utility C

*Text Input*
If User selects Utility A, they must provide an 8 digit account number.
If User selects Utility B, they must provide an 10 digit account number.
If User selects Utility C, they must provide an 12 digit account number.

Anyone know of a simply javascript solution that would provide the answer? I've beat myself to death over this.

Thanks!

Comment: Downvoted until you provide details of which aspect of a "javascript solution" you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

HTML

```
<select id="Select" onchange="checkText()">
  <option value="8"> A</option>
  <option value="10"> B</option>
  <option value="12"> C</option>
</select>

<input id="Enter" type="text" onchange="checkText()" />

<div id="Message"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function checkText(input) {
  if(document.getElementById("Enter").value.length != document.getElementById("Select").selectedOptions[0].value) {
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "Your ID has to be " + document.getElementById("Select").selectedOptions[0].value + " digits long";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

This is not brilliant at all. But I will not do your work for you. You can easily pick up from here.

I also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWY7g/)

Comment: Thanks for the start. I wasn't trying to have someone complete the work for me. Right now, I've managed to accomplish a live validation that informs the User that there is a minimum and maximum value required - however it's not based on the drop down selection. Just thought I'd ask around.

Answer (score 0):

Where `select` is your dropdown and `input` is your input string, you could use:

```
if ( !/^\d+$/.test(input) ||
    input.length != [ 8, 10, 12 ][ select.selectedIndex ] ) {
    // Input invalid
}
```

Further to @Amberland's feedback:

Or, for a more generic solution, store the number of required digits as the value of each option element, e.g. `<option value=8>Utility A</option>`, and use:

```
if ( !/^\d+$/.test(input) || input.length != select.value ) {
    // Input invalid
}
```

Comment: This is far from generic. What if there is the slightest change in your mark up concerning `<option>`?

Comment: @Amberlamps. Yes, the order of the numbers in the array must correspond to the order of the options. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: It is! But is not generic! I would never approve a solution like that.

Comment: @Amberlamps. I agree that storing the number of required digits as an attribute of each option element would be the better approach ;)

Comment: You do not need to store it anywhere. Just read it from the the `select` element.